# Group and calculate values in list

Tags: kotlin, stream

I have a list of classes (Kotlin)

```
class ChallengeRecord(
val sc: String,
val participant: String,
val hr: String,
val point: Int)
```

how can I group by participant and sum points by them?

I want to found kotlin analogue for java

```
Collectors.groupingBy() or Collectors.toMap()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.groupingBy { it.participant }
.fold(0){accumulator, element -> accumulator + element.point }
```

Comment: Could you explain some of your code, to make it easier to understand for future readers?

Answer (score -2):

```
.groupBy { it.participant }
.mapValues { (_, challengeRecords) -> challengeRecords.sumOf { it.point } }
```

Comment: I'm confused. You've left two different answers. What's the difference? Do they both work? If so, what's the benefit of one over the other?

Comment: Could you explain some of your code, to make it easier to understand for future readers?

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.